# MVC Enity Framework get KEY attribute from table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, audit

I am trying to extract the [key] value from a table.

This is for a logging method which looks like this:

```
private List<Log> GetAuditRecordsForChange(DbEntityEntry dbEntry, string userId)
{
    List<Log> result = new List<Log>();

    DateTime changeTime = DateTime.Now;

    // Get the Table() attribute, if one exists
    TableAttribute tableAttr = dbEntry.Entity.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TableAttribute), false).SingleOrDefault() as TableAttribute;

    // Get table name (if it has a Table attribute, use that, otherwise get the pluralized name)
    string tableName = tableAttr != null ? tableAttr.Name : dbEntry.Entity.GetType().Name;

    // Get primary key value
    string keyName = dbEntry.Entity.GetType().GetProperties().Single(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(KeyAttribute), false).Count() > 0).Name;

    if (dbEntry.State == EntityState.Added)
    {
        result.Add(new Log()
        {
            LogID = Guid.NewGuid(),
            EventType = "A", // Added
            TableName = tableName,
            RecordID = dbEntry.CurrentValues.GetValue<object>(keyName).ToString(), 
            ColumnName = "*ALL",
            NewValue = (dbEntry.CurrentValues.ToObject() is IDescribableEntity) ? (dbEntry.CurrentValues.ToObject() as IDescribableEntity).Describe() : dbEntry.CurrentValues.ToObject().ToString(),
            Created_by = userId,
            Created_date = changeTime
        }
            );
    }
```

The problem is to get the RecordID when a Record is added, when it get deleted or modified it works. (The code to get it is the same)

When I debug I also see that it has the KeyAttribute in the CustomAttributes base but not sure why it always shows up as 0.

I can debug more if needed

Answer (score 0):

After savechanges you can fetch the newly created key. (Guess the key is generated automatically inserting a new record).

Comment: Aha, yes it is autogenerated. So how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

for me you have several solutions.

**first solution:**

- enlist added entity from the context
- SaveChanges
- enumerate the enlisted entities to add log
- SaveChanges

the problem (or not) here is that the business and the logging are not in the same transaction.

antother problem, depending on the implementation, is to prevent loging of log of log of log... This can be donne by filtering entities by typeName for example.

**other solution:**

add and ICollection<Log> to your entities.

the problem here is to unify the logs:

- inheritance of entity, or
- several log tables + a view
- ...

**other solution**

use trigger at database level

**other solution**

..., use cdc if you have Sql Server Enterprise Edition

Comment: Hmmm so it's not possible to just update the RecordID field after the first SavingChanges? And how can I code it to NOT log that? Some examples would be great.

Comment: Thought about a thing but doubt its very good practice. When you create a new record just add it to the DB with no values (NULL) (will be missing [required] tagging) And then just UPDATE the newly created row instead and then dont listen for newly added rows, just listen on Updated rows. Not really what I wanna do but would that work?